# Add a literal git repository to a git repository

Tags: git, version-control

I have some code, version controlled using git, that itself uses git to version control some of the data managed by the code. The data is in a separate repository and everything works fine.

However, the tests currently setup fresh git repositories before each test, but the code to bring these repos into their initial state keeps growing. It would be more convenient to be able to include a default git repo for the tests within the repo itself.

It's no problem to create a nested `test/data/test_repo` with files and a git repository, but it seems impossible to actually add the `.git` directory to git. For example, `git add -f test/data/test_repo` results in

```
$ git add -f test/data/test_repo/.git/
error: Invalid path 'test/data/test_repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG'
error: unable to add test/data/test_repo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

Is there a way to achieve this or is it simply impossible?

**Use case:** For running unit test

1. The nested git repo is a unit test fixture.
2. Not require internet access during test runs to pull down the nested repo.

Comment: Do you mean you want your code repo including the `test_repo` (default)? You can add `test_repo` as a submodule for your code repo by `git submodule add test test/data/test_repo`.

Comment: Yes. That is indeed a possibility, but to distribute that to my colleagues, the submodule would need to be backed by a remote repo. It would also bring the extra hassle of dealing with a submodule with it. I think the net effect of that would be negative.

Comment: So how do you manage the code repo now, just manage it locally with your colleagues?

Comment: The code itself is backed by a remote git repo. Perhaps my past experiences with submodules have made me too wary: managing them and ensuring everyone also updates those when pulling was quite a challenge. It seems overkill for this purpose. But you are probably right that that is the way you are intended to achieve something like this.

Comment: Ok, understanding your concern. I added another solution for you to refer.

Answer (score 1):

Create the default git repo and pack it up into a zipfile or tarball. Add that to your repo.

Comment: That's a splendid idea. That would reduce the burden to extracting a file.

Answer (score 1):

You may try git submodule https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule
to make test_repo as a submodule of your test repo

Comment: A submodule would indeed work, but as I explain in my response to the comment by @marina-msft, I think that wouldn't improve matters for my case. I should have mentioned my thoughts on the 'submodule' option in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution:

1. In the test_repo, bundle test_repo by `git bundle create test_repo.bundle master`.
2. Add the test_repo.bundle file in your code repo.

See [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle#_examples)

Comment: This option is nice since you can use `git` to mange the archive and do incremental updates.